# Forward port to virtual IP in namespace

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding, namespaces

So, I followed this guide to make a namespace where I can run my VPN:
https://schnouki.net/posts/2014/12/12/openvpn-for-a-single-application-on-linux/

It works fine so far, but I have one problem. I want to run a service in the namespace that opens a port I can user via browser on another PC.

So, I guess I have to forward the port that goes into my normal network to the virtual network in the namespace, but I can't figure out, how I actually do that.

Here is the output of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:f5:59:ab
          inet addr:192.168.0.8  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:73328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:125290 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:10329389 (9.8 MiB)  TX bytes:100230154 (95.5 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3356 (3.2 KiB)  TX bytes:3356 (3.2 KiB)

vpn0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ee:d1:1a:2e:22:56
          inet addr:10.200.200.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:118651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:67092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:97664362 (93.1 MiB)  TX bytes:10833521 (10.3 MiB)
```

Comment: Your system will have to act as router. Is forwarding enabled? `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: part of the tutorial I used is `sysctl -q net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, so I guess it is enabled.